# Generate non linear html table based on SQL read result

Tags: php, sql, html-table

I'm a Brazilian soldier making a system in a way to make the military eat in our local refectory. This is the LibreOffice Calc model I'm using as example:

[image]

For this, they need to check if they want to eat the breakfast, lunch, dinner and supper. I Already got this information in this array that came from my SQL database:

```
$from_sql_db_data = array(
    array (
    'posto' =>  'CAP' ,
      'numero' => null  ,
      'nome' =>  'MUENZER' ,
      'cafe' =>  'X' ,
      'almoco' =>  'X' ,
      'jantar' =>  'X' ,
      'ceia' =>  'X' ,
    ),
    array (
      'posto' =>  'TEN' ,
      'numero' =>  null ,
      'nome' =>  'CAPRILE' ,
      'cafe' =>  'X' ,
      'almoco' =>  'X' ,
      'jantar' =>  'X' ,
      'ceia' =>  'X' ,
    ),
    array (
    'posto' =>  'ST' ,
      'numero' =>  null ,
      'nome' =>  'JEILTON' ,
      'cafe' =>  'X' ,
      'almoco' =>  'X' ,
      'jantar' =>  'X' ,
      'ceia' =>  'X' ,
    ),
    array (
    'posto' =>  'SGT' ,
      'numero' =>  null ,
      'nome' =>  'DANILO' ,
      'cafe' =>  'X' ,
      'almoco' =>  'X' ,
      'jantar' =>  'X' ,
      'ceia' =>  'X' ,
    ),
    array (
    'posto' =>  'SGT' ,
      'numero' =>  null ,
      'nome' =>  'RESENDE' ,
      'cafe' =>  'X' ,
      'almoco' =>  'X' ,
      'jantar' =>  'X' ,
      'ceia' =>  'X' ,
    ),
    array (
    'posto' =>  'CB' ,
      'numero' =>  '203' ,
      'nome' =>  'gonzaga' ,
      'cafe' =>  'X' ,
      'almoco' =>  'X' ,
      'jantar' =>  'X' ,
      'ceia' =>  'X' ,
    ),
    array (
      'posto' =>  'CB' ,
      'numero' =>  '202' ,
      'nome' =>  'elias',
      'cafe' =>  'X' ,
      'almoco' =>  'X' ,
      'jantar' =>  'X' ,
      'ceia' =>  'X' ,
    ),
    array (
      'posto' =>  'SD EP',
      'numero' =>  '490' ,
      'nome' =>  'luiz' ,
      'cafe' =>  'X'  ,
      'almoco' =>  'X'  ,
      'jantar' =>  'X'  ,
      'ceia' =>  'X'  ,
    ),
    array (
      'posto' =>  'SD EP'  ,
      'numero' =>  '448'  ,
      'nome' =>  'guedes'  ,
      'cafe' =>  'X'  ,
      'almoco' =>  'X'  ,
      'jantar' =>  'X'  ,
      'ceia' =>  'X'  ,
    ),
    array (
      'posto' =>  'SD EP'  ,
      'numero' =>  '488'  ,
      'nome' =>  'julio'  ,
      'cafe' =>  'X'  ,
      'almoco' =>  'X'  ,
      'jantar' =>  'X'  ,
      'ceia' =>  'X'  ,
    ),
    array (
      'posto' =>  'SD EV'  ,
      'numero' =>  '605'  ,
      'nome' =>  'heitor'  ,
      'cafe' =>  'X'  ,
      'almoco' => null,
      'jantar' => null,
      'ceia' => null,
    )    
  );
```

The name of the military are grouped according to their rank OFICIAIS(officers), SARGENTOS (sergeants), CABO (Corporal), SD EP(Soldier) and SD EV (Recruit). The information needs to be segmented cause its can be impressed in an A4 paper. For the moment, what I could do was this:

```html
<?php

  $from_sql_db_data = array(
    array (
    'posto' =>  'CAP' ,
      'numero' => null  ,
      'nome' =>  'MUENZER' ,
      'cafe' =>  'X' ,
      'almoco' =>  'X' ,
      'jantar' =>  'X' ,
      'ceia' =>  'X' ,
    ),
    array (
      'posto' =>  'TEN' ,
      'numero' =>  null ,
      'nome' =>  'CAPRILE' ,
      'cafe' =>  'X' ,
      'almoco' =>  'X' ,
      'jantar' =>  'X' ,
      'ceia' =>  'X' ,
    ),
    array (
    'posto' =>  'ST' ,
      'numero' =>  null ,
      'nome' =>  'JEILTON' ,
      'cafe' =>  'X' ,
      'almoco' =>  'X' ,
      'jantar' =>  'X' ,
      'ceia' =>  'X' ,
    ),
    array (
    'posto' =>  'SGT' ,
      'numero' =>  null ,
      'nome' =>  'DANILO' ,
      'cafe' =>  'X' ,
      'almoco' =>  'X' ,
      'jantar' =>  'X' ,
      'ceia' =>  'X' ,
    ),
    array (
    'posto' =>  'SGT' ,
      'numero' =>  null ,
      'nome' =>  'RESENDE' ,
      'cafe' =>  'X' ,
      'almoco' =>  'X' ,
      'jantar' =>  'X' ,
      'ceia' =>  'X' ,
    ),
    array (
    'posto' =>  'CB' ,
      'numero' =>  '203' ,
      'nome' =>  'gonzaga' ,
      'cafe' =>  'X' ,
      'almoco' =>  'X' ,
      'jantar' =>  'X' ,
      'ceia' =>  'X' ,
    ),
    array (
      'posto' =>  'CB' ,
      'numero' =>  '202' ,
      'nome' =>  'elias',
      'cafe' =>  'X' ,
      'almoco' =>  'X' ,
      'jantar' =>  'X' ,
      'ceia' =>  'X' ,
    ),
    array (
      'posto' =>  'SD EP',
      'numero' =>  '490' ,
      'nome' =>  'luiz' ,
      'cafe' =>  'X'  ,
      'almoco' =>  'X'  ,
      'jantar' =>  'X'  ,
      'ceia' =>  'X'  ,
    ),
    array (
      'posto' =>  'SD EP'  ,
      'numero' =>  '448'  ,
      'nome' =>  'guedes'  ,
      'cafe' =>  'X'  ,
      'almoco' =>  'X'  ,
      'jantar' =>  'X'  ,
      'ceia' =>  'X'  ,
    ),
    array (
      'posto' =>  'SD EP'  ,
      'numero' =>  '488'  ,
      'nome' =>  'julio'  ,
      'cafe' =>  'X'  ,
      'almoco' =>  'X'  ,
      'jantar' =>  'X'  ,
      'ceia' =>  'X'  ,
    ),
    array (
      'posto' =>  'SD EV'  ,
      'numero' =>  '605'  ,
      'nome' =>  'heitor'  ,
      'cafe' =>  'X'  ,
      'almoco' => null,
      'jantar' => null,
      'ceia' => null,
    )    
  );


?>

<table summary="militares arranchados" class="table table-bordered table-hover" border="1">          
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="7">
                2º CIA DE FUZILEIROS
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="7">
                ARRANCHAMENTO DIA 6 DE NOVEMBRO DE 2018
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="7">
                ARRANCHAMENTO DIA 6 (TERCA-FEIRA) DE NOVEMBRO DE 2018 
              </td>
            </tr>  
            <tr>
              <th>IDENTIFICADOR</th>
              <th>CAFE</th>
              <th>ALMOCO</th>
              <th>JANTAR</th>
              <th>CEIA</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
<?php
  if($from_sql_db_data){
    $quantidadeArrays = count($from_sql_db_data);
    for ($x = 0; $x < $quantidadeArrays ;$x++){
      $parray = ($from_sql_db_data[$x]); 
        echo "\n<tr>\n";
        echo "<td>".$parray['posto']." ".$parray['numero']." ".$parray['nome']." "."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$parray['cafe']."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$parray['almoco']."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$parray['jantar']."</td>\n";
        echo "<td>".$parray['ceia']."</td>\n";
    }   
  }
?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you want here?  ... The same table output as the LibreOffice, or something else?

Comment: Generate a html table based on my sql query